# Surface Area and Volume Measurements

Tags: measurement

I am fairly new to Blender and I'm hoping to find a way to easily calculate surface area and volume of irregular objects in Blender. I was looking into the Measureit addon, however it seems that I would have to break the measurements up and add them together since the objects I am working with are irregular (I'm modeling animals). Is there any add on that would help to enable this, or perhaps anything regarding coding in Blender?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### 3D print toolbox

In the [3D print toolbox add-on](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox) (it's already bundled with the official verion of Blender, you just have to enable it) there are two buttons (you can fin the right on the top of the tab), one for the volume and one for the surface (area)

Results are shown in the latest line of the panel once one of the two buttons is pressed.

[image]

The commands take into account the whole object, so if you need to get the surface of one part of your object only, you'll have to separate the faces into another object.